# props as callback to parent of parent in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I know how to set callback using props to parent component. I do that as in official react tutorial. But suppose I want to pass props to parent of parent. Suppose I have components as follows:

```html
AllergyBox
  AllergiesList
    Allergy
```

I want to implement allergy delete function. AllergyBox owns the state of list of allergies and passes it down as prop. Whenever Allergy delete button is clicked i want to delete that Allergy and refresh UI.
So what i try:

```html
var Allergy = React.createClass({
    deleteAllergy: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var allergy_id = this.props.id;
        this.props.onAllergyDelete({
           id: allergy_id
        });
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <li>{this.props.name} <a href="#" onClick={this.deleteAllergy}> </a></li>
        )
    }
});
```

And Allergy List looks like that:

```html
var AllergiesList = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function(){
      return {allergies: []}
    },
    sendAllergyDelete: function(id){
      this.props.onSendAllergyDelete({
          id: id
      })
    },
    render:function(){
        var allergies = this.props.allergies.map(function(allergy){
            return(
                <Allergy name={allergy.name} key={allergy.id} id={allergy.id} onAllergyDelete={this.sendAllergyDelete} />
            )
        });
        return(
            <ul>
                {allergies}
            </ul>
        )
    }
});
```

And I have AllergyBox component that should handle my delete:

```html
var AllergyBox = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
      return {
          allergiesList: [],
          form: []
      }
    },
    
    handleAllergyDelete: function(id){
      alert(id);
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className="allergies">
                <AllergiesList allergies={this.state.allergiesList} onSendAllergyDelete={this.handleAllergyDelete} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

But I have error in Allergy component:

```html
this.props.onAllergyDelete is not a function
```

I am new to React, so I don't know what is the best solution to pass something up through the components hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set `this` for `.map` in `AllergiesList`, because by default `this` in `.map` callback refers to global scope(in browser it is `window`) or if you use `strict mode` this will be `undefined`. When you pass `this.sendAllergyDelete` as a argument, you don't pass reference to function - you pass `window.sendAllergyDelete` that equal `undefined`, because in `window` there is no `sendAllergyDelete` function

```
var allergies = this.props.allergies.map(function(allergy) {
  return (
    <Allergy 
      name={allergy.name} 
      key={allergy.id} 
      id={allergy.id} 
      onAllergyDelete={this.sendAllergyDelete} />
  )
}, this);
   ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

```html
var that = this;
var allergies = this.props.allergies.map(function(allergy){
    return(
         <Allergy onAllergyDelete={that.handleAllergyDelete} name={allergy.name} key={allergy.id} id={allergy.id} />
         )
});
```

I declared variable that to be equal to this (component). So, inside .map I could use that.handleAllergyDelete.